# An increase in the bootstrap modal's height hides the top modal's cotent and I can't scroll up top to view the content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I am working with a bootstrap Modal but when ever the content inside the Modal's body increase's, the top Modal's content are hidden up in the scroll view and I can't scroll up to view it.

Screenshots.

1. The modal's body content before it has grown[image].
2. The Modal's body content after there's an addition of content in the modal's Body.
   [image]

How can I fix this?
And if I can, can I do it without getting scroll bars?

Comment: Likely because its centered vertically in the css, which you dont show. Edit the css and when you do the include append it with `?v=2` so the browser doesnt use cache

Answer (score 0):

I hope your problem solved by bellow code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .modal-body{
    max-height:calc(100vh - 200px) !important;
    overflow-y:auto
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div style="height:1000px">
                content with height 1000px
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I Hope to let me know the result. and if its ok set this question answered. thanks a lot